# How to guide org users to visit in-house documents and best practices

Tags: lightning-web-components, bestpractice, custom, setup, popup

I have created a few best practices and guideline documents for our org users. It includes our orgs practices, limits, what should be the process etc. stuff.
But the problem is: all these documents are hosted over Confluence. If we want to make awareness of these docs and actually implement, we will have to ask all the users to read docs and all. So I was thinking: What if we can redirect them to these docs, when they are actually going to make changes in the org?

To explain this better, we will take example of custom settings: We have a nice internal document for best practices while creating custom setrings in our org.
So if someone is going to setup->custom settings-> new, there should be a pop-up, or help text or something saying "hey, please read this or consider these points before creating" and there we can add a link to our Confluence documents.

What are our options and implementation for this use case, as we can not modify setup pages?

Comment: Have you considered using [In-App Guidance](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customhelp_lexguid.htm&language=en_US&type=5)?

Comment: This is game changer for my use case Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to guide your users is to use [In-App Guidance](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customhelp_lexguid.htm&language=en_US&type=5), a feature built in to the Salesforce UI.

It allows for tutorial-like steps to be shown, as well as other forms of prompting.